# Compare char and const string

Tags: c++

In the context of creating a part of an 3D-engine I'm stuck in a basic C++ problem.

```
#include <iostream>

//Ignore this function
std::string get_replacement(char c) {return "TEEEEEEEST";}

int main() {
    //Declaring some variables
    std::string const& foo = "X";
    std::string str = "FFFFGGGGXFFWEFWXFFFF";
    const int N = 4;    //Amount of iterations
    //These values and types can't be changed
    //----------------------------------------


    //String before changement
    std::cout << "Before: " << str << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (char c : str) {
            if (c == foo) {     //How to do this????
                str += get_replacement(c);
            } else str += c;
        }   
    }   

    std::cout << "After: " << str << std::endl;

}
```

The problem is on line 20: *test.cpp:20:19: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘char’ and ‘const string {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string}’)*

It works when I replace foo with a literal character like 'X'. However that is not dynamic. I tried to search a solution and tried stuff like .c_str() but without success.

**Edit:**
**The type of foo can't be changed AND MUST BE std::string const&** because I use a library of school where a configuration file is read with that type.

Comment: Dont declare `foo` as a const ref. That makes no sense.

Comment: try `c == foo.front()` (or if you are paranoid: `foo.size() && c == foo.front()`)

Comment: Why not just declare foo as a char?

Comment: "However that is not dynamic" what do you mean by that?

Comment: @SombreroChicken Read the edit

Comment: @Bathsheba I can replace foo with 'X', but what if the config file says foo should be 'Y'? I don't want to hardcode the character

Comment: As exposed in the sample code, SombreroChicken's hint is justified...

Comment: But `std::string const& foo = "X";` looks pretty hardcoded to me.

Comment: A string is an arbitrary number of characters. Even if it happens to only contain one character, it is still a fundamentally different type from char. Look at the docs for std::string to get one character from the string.

Comment: @Bathsheba Because it's a simulation of the problem... This is the code in the engine: std::string const& initiator = l_system.get_initiator();

Comment: *"It works when I replace foo with a literal character like 'X'"* - You are doing something fishy if it does. Post your compiler options as well, please.

Comment: @O'Niel What's stopping you from storing `foo` as a `const char` instead of `const std::string`? Comparing a single `char`, to a collection of `char`s (`std::string`) doesn't really make a lot of sense.

Comment: Alternatively, `std::string(&c, 1) == foo` or something. It depends on what you want to happen if `foo` is longer than 1 char.

Comment: Well, if you persist with that type, then you could use `c == foo[0]`, but that's reasonably horrible.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? Change parts of a string to possibly longer strings? Like some kind of search and replace?

Comment: @doctorlove Yes, for implementing a L-system

Comment: Perhaps you need to recurse e.g. if character = 'X' then ... etc... How long will the string get?

Comment: What does your school's library have to do with how you declare your variables?

Comment: @melpomene Maybe because I have to use the same type as the function returning the variable??

Comment: @O'Niel Why do you think you have to use the same type?

Comment: std::string foo = int test(return 5;)   wont work for example I guess? @melpomene

Comment: A safe way to do this is `c == foo.c_str()[0]`.  `foo[0]` will throw if foo is empty,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it explicit that you only care about the first character.

```
if (c == foo[0])
```

Or convert the character to a string (this is less efficient).

```
if (std::string(1, c) == foo)
```

Both methods fail miserably if you work with non-ascii strings (unicode or some other multi byte representation).

Comment: Prefer the second way - that's almost acceptable - stuff the performance, will be negligible cf. I/O. +1.

Comment: I don't agree.  If working with UTF16, comparison will either compile, or not, depending on the char type of the single char value.  If working with UTF8, the value stored in a single char value will usually hold an ASCII char, and the comparison will work.  The performance difference is not so negligible, since comparing single chars is a couple of instructions on most machines, including fetching.  Creating a string - even a short one, is an order of magnitude more than that.

Answer (score 1):

A few solutions that can deal with empty strings, but also doesn't involve dynamic allocation of a new `std::string` (although, smart implementations do avoid dynamic allocation with small string optimization anyway):

```
if(foo().size() == 1
&& c == foo.front())
```

Or

```
char str[] = {c, '\0'};
if (str == foo)
```

If you don't mind relying on small string optimization, then this is perhaps simpler:

```
if (std::string{c} == foo)
```